# Android Studio - Access resources from another package in manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-resources

I am implementing an `Android` application that has both live and office packages other then the main package. The `manifest` file is included inside the main package. The `ic_launcher` and `app_name` resources are included in both live and office for production and development versions, respectively.

When I try to access `ic_launcher` and `app_name` from the `manifest` file, it fails to read them - as show in this screen shot -.

[image]

This is the hierarchy of my app:

[image]

The resources I try to access are included under both live and office directories.

Is there anything I should add to be able to access them from `manifest` file?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with live and office? You might be misusing flavors.